# Layout alias does not work

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I have created two layouts `activity_filter_onepane.xml` and `activity_filter_twopane.xml`. Then I created a resource directory `values-sw600dp-land`. Inside it `(/res/values-sw600dp-land)`, I created a file layout.xml which contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="activity_filter" type="layout">@layout/activity_filter_twopane</item>
    <bool name="has_two_panes">true</bool>
</resources>
```

I created another file `layout.xml` under the folder `/res/values` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="activity_filter" type="layout">@layout/activity_filter_onepane</item>
    <bool name="has_two_panes">false</bool>
</resources>
```

Then, my activity `FilterActivity` loads activity_filter as follows in `onCreate():`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter);
```

I have been following [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseOriQuali) for this.
This does not seem to work. It appears to always load the activity_filter_onepane layout in both orientations.

Comment: Are you testing with 2 devices, say a small phone and a tablet?

Comment: @Alessio yes one phone emulator and one tablet emulator. Also I switch between orientations and no effect.

Comment: maybe values-sw600dp-land should be directly under /res directory not under /res/values ?

Comment: Not so sure what you're trying to accomplish, but if you want simply to use two different layouts (one for phone, one for tablets), put the phone one in "res/layout/my_activity.xml" and the tablet one in "res/layout-sw600dp/my_activity.xml". Note: you need to use 'layout' folder name, not values.

Comment: You can treat resources like dimensions (if you need them) differently, so if you need a boolean that can go into "res/values" and "res/values-sw600dp" respectively

Comment: @RafalMalek you are right, I mis-typed it. I have used the correct path in project. Still fails